# How can I find the entries with dates older then a specified date in a list but all data types are string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

I have been asked to find all the entries in a list that are older then a user input date. Problem is that the list got data from a textfile and the date is not in datetime format, but rather string(YYYY/MM/DD).

How do I go about doing this? I have fetched the data, separated it, saved it in an object and a list of objects.

Textfile:

```cs
John,Smith,02/05/1969,1,700000,Manager,None
Jane,Doe,04/01/1977,2,600000,Employee,John
Jim,Bean,11/09/1985,3,650000,Employee,Jane
Roger,Wilco,19/12/1990,4,200000,Trainee,Jane
Susan,Roe,22/06/1995,5,180000,Trainee,Jane
```

Controller:

```
    // GET: HRManager
            public ActionResult HRManager()
            {
                List<EmployeeViewModel> employees= GetTestData();
                return View(employees);
            }

                private List<EmployeeViewModel> GetTestData()
            {

                string[] Lines;
                string filepath = @"D:Employees.txt";
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath);
                string Name;
                string Surname;
                string Birthdate;
                int EmpNum;
                int Salary;
                string Role;
                string Reports;
                List<EmployeeViewModel> employees = new      List<EmployeeViewModel>();

                while (file.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    //Read textfile
                    Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

                    //Seperate data and assign
                    foreach (string line in Lines)
                    {
                        string[] L = line.Split(',');
                        Name = L[0];
                        Surname = L[1];
                        Birthdate = L[2];
                        EmpNum = Convert.ToInt32(L[3]);
                        Salary = Convert.ToInt32(L[4]);
                        Role = L[5];
                        Reports = L[6];

                    //Send to ViewModel
                    EmployeeViewModel emp = new EmployeeViewModel(Name,         Surname, Birthdate, EmpNum, Salary, Role, Reports);
                    employees.Add(emp);
                    return employees;
                    }

                }
                file.Close();
                return (employees);

            }
```

View:

```
        public class EmployeeViewModel
        {
            public string _Name { get; set; }
            public string _Surname { get; set; }
            public string _Birthdate { get; set; }
            public int _EmpNum { get; set; }
            public int _Salary { get; set; }
            public string _Role { get; set; }
            public string _Reports { get; set; }

            public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, string         birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
            {
                _Name = name;
                _Surname = surname;
                _Birthdate = birthdate;
                _EmpNum = empnum;
                _Salary = salary;
                _Role = role;
                _Reports = reports;
            }
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
        public class EmployeeViewModel
        {
            public string _Name { get; set; }
            public string _Surname { get; set; }
            public string _Birthdate { get; set; }
            public int _EmpNum { get; set; }
            public int _Salary { get; set; }
            public string _Role { get; set; }
            public string _Reports { get; set; }

            public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, string birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
            {
                _Name = name;
                _Surname = surname;
                _Birthdate = birthdate;
                _EmpNum = empnum;
                _Salary = salary;
                _Role = role;
                _Reports = reports;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How does your list look like? Do you have separate properties for your columns?Please provide some code.

Comment: @wertzui Provided code

Comment: Make the object a DateTime then in code use Birthdate = DateTime.Parse(L[2]);

Comment: I did this and now i get this error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Something to do with the text file not having the right datetime format? @wertzui

Comment: DateTimeOffset.Parse will use your current culture. Depending on your system settings. this may not match the culture used in the text file. You need to ensure that the culture used for parsing is able to parse the format "DD/MM/YYYY" as defined in the text file. In my answer I used the german culture "de" which can parse it just fine.

Comment: Try DateTime.TryParseExact and give it the format you are expecting the date to come in as, then set a breakpoint on the false and see if you are getting some empty rows, or bad data in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is changing Birtdate to a DateTimeOffset and then use the `Parse` Method.
Aside from that, I also cleaned your code a little bit up and fixed the wrong use of the `IDosposable` stream reader.

```
private async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<EmployeeViewModel>> GetTestData()
{

    var filepath = @"D:\Employees.txt";
    var employees = new List<EmployeeViewModel>();

    using(var reader = File.OpenText(filepath))
    {
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var columns = line.Split(',');
            var employee = new EmployeeViewModel(columns[0], columns[1], DateTimeOffset.Parse(columns[2], new CultureInfo("de")), int.Parse(columns[3]), int.Parse(columns[4]), columns[5], columns[6]);
            employees.Add(employee);
        }
    }

    return employees;
}

public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Surname { get; }
    public DateTimeOffset Birthdate { get;  }
    public int EmpNum { get; }
    public int Salary { get; }
    public string Role { get; }
    public string Reports { get; }

    public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, DateTimeOffset birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Birthdate = birthdate;
        EmpNum = empnum;
        Salary = salary;
        Role = role;
        Reports = reports;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ViewModel constructor to convert string input to DateTime:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    private readonly string[] validDateFormats =
        {
            "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", "MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt", "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
            "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", "MMM dd, yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-M-dd", "yyyy-M-d", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
            "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt"
        };

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public int EmpNum { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Reports { get; set; }

    public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, string birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
    {
        DateTime outValue;

        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Birthdate = DateTime.TryParseExact(birthdate, validDateFormats, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out outValue)
                    ? outValue : (DateTime?)null;
        EmpNum = empnum;
        Salary = salary;
        Role = role;
        Reports = reports;
    }
}
```

then later, you can query via linq:

```
employees.Where(e => e.BirthDate == dtYourInputDate);
```

Hope this helps.